# Recover Outlook Mail from library folder on the hard disk

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-outlook

An E-mail I received from my colleague has gone missing from outlook, and from the chain of all replies. I assume there is a way it can be recalled by the sender, but I need proof this email was sent. When I search the Hard disk I can find the E-mail in the library folder, but it won't let me put this back into Outlook, and when I copy the file it won't open. I can only screenshot the file, so how do I recover the email properly?

Thanks for any help

Comment: This makes no sense with the current wording of what was done... What exactly do you mean by "I can find the E-mail in the library folder", as Outlook doesn't store email databases there (`.ost`/`.pst`).

Answer (score 1):

Can you found this email via Outlook search box? It is suggested for you to firstly log in your web mail and see if you can found this missing email message.

Besides, what is the file format you found in the library folder? As I know, for messages of .eml format, we can directly dag it to your Outlook Inbox folder. If it is a .olm file, you could [import](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-email-messages-contacts-and-other-items-into-outlook-for-mac-6cc48404-a65c-4b8c-a12a-95a905249414) it to your Outlook client.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook can only natively import .pst files, and the E-mails, Calendars and Contacts are stored in .pst (Exchange accounts) and otherwise .ost (Cannot be imported) files. If the E-mail is in different format, you have to look for a way to convert it into .pst as we don't know what is it.

Or if that is a .pst file, you can import it, Open Outlook > File menu, Click Open & Export and click Import/Export > Import from another program or file > Check mark Outlook Data File (.pst) > Browse to the .pst file > and click Import items in current mailbox  > Finish.

Comment: Only exchange, and possibly POP3, accounts are saved in a `.pst` database; all others are `.ost` _(`.pst` databases can be imported, whereas `.ost` ones cannot since they're only a copy of what's on the email server and are rebuilt/updated upon a Send/Receive)_

Comment: Thank you @JW0914

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office365, you can recover all deleted emails using [eDiscovery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/ediscovery?view=o365-worldwide).